# Is there a Linux serial terminal WITH timestamps?

Tags: linux, serial-port

i still want to check my Bootloader + Linux Startupcode for an embedded device. Therefore i want to catch the time for every command printed to the serial port.

**I know** there are programs like putty (which i can dearly recommend), getty, cutecom, picocom, screen etc. **But none** of these add timestamps to the incomming messages on the host screen (I'm not really talking about the date, more like how many ms have gone since the first output). It actually sounds not like a big deal.

I found out there is one script doing what i wanted to have, called *grabserial* but it's not working properly, since it's to slow to process the whole output. I discussed this problem in a different forum (if you want to know: [grabserial problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20518737/3085931) but it's not part of the topic). So i can't use that script.

*Now again*: can you tell me a terminal for Linux which adds timestamps to every line, which was received from a Serial Port?

Thank you

[Edit:] I've found a pretty rough **workaround** with [cereal](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/554), which wants to have some settings, since it locks the port everytime you use it. In the end, it adds the actual date and time, not the startup time and difftime between each step, so as you can see I'm still looking for an adequate solution.

Comment: FYI: **grabserial** is now available at [GitHub](https://github.com/tbird20d/grabserial). You can file an issue there or provide a patch.

Comment: thanks for the advice, I'll contribute soon.

Answer (score 9):

This might come 3 years too late, but minicom (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minicom) supports timestamps for every line printed on the terminal. In Ubuntu it's directly available in the default repos.

Comment: I already moved on from that project, but have you checked if it keeps what it promises? I'm asking since I've seen a lot of terminal tools that say they will attach timestamps, but in the end didn't or at least in a very unpractical kind of way.

Comment: minicom version 2.7 (compiled Feb  7 2016), on Ubuntu 16.04.01 has visible time stamps in the format "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS", I just used it right now.

Comment: Thanks for the investigation

Comment: Now I remember minicom. It actually works quiet well. However as mentioned in the question I was benchmarking startup-times, means that the lowest unit seconds barely is precise enough. I didn't quiet understand why they put that limit

Comment: For completeness, start minicom with something like
minicom -b 9600 -D /dev/ttyUSB0 -z -C ~/logs/tty-USB0.log -8
-b baudrate
-D device to use
-z status line at the bottom of the page
-C capture file path
-8 or -7 for number of bits per character to pass unchanged.
Once started you need to type ^AN once to turn on timestamp logging and again to turn on millisecond level timestamps.

Answer (score 1):

tio found at https://tio.github.io provides various timestamp options:

```
       -t, --timestamp

          Enable line timestamp.

       --timestamp-format <format>

          Set timestamp format to any of the following timestamp formats:

          24hour          24-hour format ("hh:mm:ss.sss")

          24hour-start    24-hour format relative to start time

          24hour-delta    24-hour format relative to previous timestamp

          iso8601         ISO8601 format ("YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.sss")

          Default format is 24hour
```

In your case, showing how much time has passed since start, that would be something like this:

```
tio -t --timestamp-format 24hour-start /dev/ttyUSB0
```

Settings can also be enabled in tio configuration file ~/.tioconfig

Comment: Tio does not support timestamp in hex mode.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look in to using strace to monitor the serial port.  See [How can I monitor data on a serial port in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/940374/how-can-i-monitor-data-on-a-serial-port-in-linux)

Comment: couldn't figure anything out about strace with timestamps

Comment: Check the -t, -tt and -ttt options to strace.

Comment: i tried, it looks more like debugging the host-serial-port. In the end, i think it looks like cereal (as mentioned in the edit).

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to build the binary by yourself, you can try a branched picocom (https://github.com/codepox/picocom).  This is based on picocom 1.7 which is a little old.

I have forked and enhanced this picocom and made it be able to show either delta-time or wall-clock timestamp.  You can find it [here](https://github.com/tdwong/picocom-with-timestamp) (https://github.com/tdwong/picocom-with-timestamp).  You still have to build the binary by yourself.

Here is how I use it.  Note,  N is the command to enable/toggle timestamp.

```
$ picocom -b 115200 /dev/ttyUSB0
  ...
<ctrl-a> N      # enable delta-time timestamp
<ctrl-a> N      # toggle wall-clock timestamp
<ctrl-a> N      # disable timestamp
```

Answer (score -3):

I believe that [ExtraPuTTY](http://www.extraputty.com/) is the solution you are looking for.

However, I wasn't clear if you wanted something to run ON Linux or just to be able to monitor it (SSH to Linux).  If you didn't want a Windows solution, then I apologize.

2023-05-05 Edit:  My apologies, I did not have any way of knowing that the link I provided 8 years ago now goes to some consulting company.  I was using extraputty at the time and did not intentionally link a company to promote it.  [Here](https://web.archive.org/web/20150516155956/http://www.extraputty.com/) is the link to archive.org showing the site as it was at the time I made this post.

Comment: This just takes me to some consulting company.

Comment: I believe he means SuperPuTTY, but yes can confirm extraputty link goes to some consulting company.
https://code.google.com/archive/p/superputty/wikis/Documentation.wiki#:~:text=SuperPutty%20is%20a%20Windows%20application,when%20multiple%20connections%20are%20used.